# How to merge the same items in the array using proxy?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, proxy, include

I have 2 objects like this:

```
var customerA = {firstName: "Dravid, Tendulkar"},
    customerB = {firstName: "Virendra, Virat, Tendulkar"};
```

I want to find same names from those strings and merge them by using `Proxy`, but I can't go further more than this:

```
var customerA = {firstName: "Dravid, Tendulkar"},
    customerB = {firstName: "Virendra, Virat, Tendulkar"};

var proxyMerge = new Proxy([customerA, customerB], {
  get: (target, keyName) => {
    let arr = target.map(item => item[keyName]);
    let output = arr.filter(item => arr[item] == arr.includes(item)); // returns an empty array.
    return output;
  }
})

var customers = proxyMerge.firstName;
console.log(customers); // the output should be: ["Dravid, Tendulkar, Virendra, Virat"]
```

How can I get a complete array has no same names?

Comment: I see absolutely no good reason to use a proxy here. Just create a new plain object and store arrays in it which you fill from a loop over all properties.

Comment: @Bergi You're right, but still just for practice though. The way using proxy like this is more understandable for me to get used to its concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine results from the `map` function. You'll have two strings as a result, so joining them to a single string and then splitting them back to a single array should do that.

Then use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object to filter out any duplicates. A `Set` can only contain unique values, so any duplicate will not be added to the set. Then with the spread operator `...` turn the `Set` back into an array and return that as an output.

Now you'll have an array without any duplicate values.

```js
var customerA = {firstName: "Dravid, Tendulkar"},
    customerB = {firstName: "Virendra, Virat, Tendulkar"};

var proxyMerge = new Proxy([customerA, customerB], {
  get: (target, keyName) => {
    let names = target.map(item => item[keyName]);
    let combined = names.join(', ').split(', ');
    let output = [...new Set(combined)];
    return output;
  }
})

var customers = proxyMerge.firstName;
console.log(customers); // the output should be: ["Dravid, Tendulkar, Virendra, Virat"]
```

Comment: Crazy. I didn't know that the keyword `Set` can be used alone like this. Thank you so much.

Comment: `Set` is not exactly (just) a keyword; [a set type ensures value equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Value_equality); and because set types are iterable and as shown with the above example, it had to be used along with [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals) or with e.g. [`Array.from(new Set(combined))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).